# Multigraphs with a given degree sequence

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics, graph-theory, integer-partitions

This challenge will give you an input of a [degree sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DegreeSequence.html) in the form of a partition of an even number. Your goal will be to write a program that will output the number of loop-free labeled multigraphs that have this degree sequence.

### Example

For example, given the input `[3,3,1,1]`, you should output the number of labeled multigraphs on four vertices \$\{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4\}\$ such that \$\deg(v_1) = \deg(v_2) = 3\$ and \$\deg(v_3) = \deg(v_4) = 1\$. In this example, there are three such multigraphs:

[image: multigraphs corresponding to (3,3,1,1)]

See Gus Wiseman's links on OEIS sequence [A209816](https://oeis.org/A209816) for more examples.

### Target data

```
input           | output
----------------+--------
[6,2]           | 0
[5,3,2]         | 1
[3,3,1,1]       | 3
[4,3,1,1,1]     | 6
[4,2,1,1,1,1]   | 10
[1,1,1,1,1,1]   | 15
[3,2,2,2,1]     | 15
[2,2,2,2,2]     | 22
[7,6,5,4,3,2,1] | 7757
```

## Challenge

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in bytes wins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 57 bytes

```hs
f(h:t)=sum[f l|l<-mapM(\n->[0..n])t,sum t-sum l==h]
f _=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDNCsIwEITvfYpBPDSYFhOtBzF9Aj15TIMUaamYVjEpXnz3mLT@IJjAMt8OzGbTlOZcae1cHTdrS4TpW1lDP/QmacvrLi66JJfzNO0UsdSbsEmoWohGRTUOgjlbGXssTWUgICFXlCsKmdHFKBZeMMqCXI7yDXyEgBF@jmSUfc2QwYc7AH/BkL6iGQ2x/F/K2/RTFVQUteWp848MiyEuNJIc197u7W3bYQrTXO7QmM0wCc4kqKEX@w8hBJ893RM)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 127 bytes

```hs
e=[]:e
h a b=mapM id$b<$a
f a=length[0|x<-h a$h a[0..maximum a],x==foldr(zipWith(:))e x,all(<1)$zipWith(!!)x[0..],map sum x==a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY2xCsMgFEX3fMULOCjYkKwhfkKnDB3E4YVolWoSEkOl9N@thRbuXS7ncC0eD@19zlpI1evKAsIkAm5XcDOZBoKVARReL/doZftOw6UgpFS2TRMwuXAGQMWTEGb1805fbru5aGnPmIbE0Xs6dIz857pm6asqXk7gKHIxUeWAbhHzWm1nHONODrs@iZEdh19U/gA)

Very very inefficient (superexponential), but I believe it should work in theory. Exceeds Tio's 60 second limit with `[3, 3, 1, 1]` as input, but works with `[1, 1, 1, 1]`.

Considers the adjacency matrices of the multigraphs.

`h a$h a[0..maximum a]` is a list of all square matrices with entries between `0` and `maximum a`, with size `length a`.

`x==foldr(zipWith(:))e x` checks if a matrix is symmetric.

`all(<1)$zipWith(!!)x[0..]` checks that the diagonal entries are zero, since there are no loops.

`map sum x==a` checks that each vertex has the proper degree.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 75 bytes

```hs
f(h:t)=sum$f<$>h%t
f[]=1
r%(h:t)=[h-i:x|i<-[0..r],x<-(r-i)%t]
r%_=[[]|r==0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9dC8IgFIbv/RWH2GBjGmkfFzH7BXXV5UlixIYjV6FGXfTf19z6IEhvnsdX3qO6cMfSmLatEr30qXTXJqryaKVjTypUkhMbDwlqVi/vjzpnOBmPraL3nCWW1WnsVXdpLxHVw0o5Ua0vnT8UrnQgAQEXVCgKOKfTAaYdcMoDzgZ8ixgkKIGfhZzybxg6RL97ES/p2xd0TkOt@NfyDrupChQhTVGfukc2xWUDyc4AW8Hl6rferk8QgdPnGxjIMhiFZBSoP0sqMGkKn3@2Tw)

It's faster (and easier to understand) when `i<-[0..r]` is replaced by `i<-[0..min r h]`. Also, it's faster to give the degrees (whose order obviously doesn't matter) in increasing order.

Comment: `i<-[0..h]` seems to be the better way to trade time for code length...